# Retrieving UITextField data from Custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm trying to retrieve the textfield data from custom cell after tap button which is placed in last cell of index, that means my table have a submit button to retrieve the data from custom cell, for that reason I placed my button in `xib` and loaded after my array count, for that I written code like this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


return [[dic_demo objectForKey:@"Demo"] count]+1;


}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];



if (indexPath==pathToLastRow)
{
   // for submit button through xib 
}  

else
 {
normal custom cell for textfields
 }

 }
```

to retreive the data i written code like this

```
 [mutarr_txt_TCelltext removeAllObjects];



        for (int i =0; i<[[dic_demo objectForKey:@"Demo"] count]; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];


            CustomTableViewCell *cell  = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tbl_SBeneficiaries cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];



                for(UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews])
                {
                    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
                    {
                        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
                        NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);

                        NSString *str_txt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text];

                        NSLog(@"First text is %lu",(unsigned long)[str_txt length]);



                        if ([str_txt length]>1) {

                            [mutarr_txt_TCelltext addObject:str_txt];

            }





    }


            }}
```

but my problem is not getting first indexpath tetxtfield data & remaining textfield data is retreving. Could anyone help on this,Please find my screen shots

[image: Added button at array count+1]

Comment: Do you have more cells than can fit on the screen at once? Personally, I think this is a bad approach. Cells are for displaying data, not providing it. You should make the controller the delegate of the text fields, and implement one or more of the text field delegate methods. When the user is finished editing, update your model with the text field's text.

Comment: Yes, the cells will keeps on increasing dynamicaly, my requirement is to keep submit button below the tableview, in Future the table size may increse or decrase but  submit button position is always to appear dow to the table, thats why i done like that, Can you please help me to get it right... Thanks in Advance